# Coordinates of specific ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, .net-3.5, listviewitem

This is going to drive me mad. I have a WPF ListView and I try to overlay a TextBox over a double-clicked cell to emulate an Editor. This is working fine so far. I call ListView.InputHitTest(e.Position) to get the clicked item. From there I use VisualTreeHelper.GetParent() to navigate through the VisualTree and to resolve the coordinates. Fine.
Now I want, that if the user presses the cursor down, that this TextBox moves to the next Item. I tried the following attempts:

```
ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index + 1)
ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(…)
```

But both methods return null (Nothing in VB), but ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.Status returns ContainersGenerated.
How can I get the coordinates of a specific ListViewItem?

By the way: I’m limited to Framework 3.5, therefore the Grid in 4.0 is not available. Additionally I do not want to use 3rd party tools.

**Edit**
Here is some (experimental) code I use:

I use a surrounding Canvas to easily position the TextBox over the ListView. I included the DataTemplate of the first column. The rest is quite similar, so I removed this code. In addition I remove some style definitions and converters - I don't think that they are of any interest here.

```
<Canvas x:Name="Canvas">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyListViewList}"
              Name="ListView"
              MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate">
                <Border Name="NameBorder">
                    <!-- Some content for this cell here -->
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" x:Name="colName" 
                                CellTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <TextBox Name="EditorTextBox"
             Visibility="Hidden"
             BorderThickness="0">
    </TextBox>
</Canvas>
```

I register PreviewKeyDown to catch the keypress on Cursor-Down:

```
  Private Sub TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    Dim model As MyListViewModel

    model = CType(DataContext, MyListViewModel)

    Select Case e.Key
      Case Key.Down
        Dim lvp As MyListViewParameter

        If Me.editorSelectedItemIndex + 1 < model.MyListViewList.Count Then

          lvp = model.MyListViewList(Me.editorSelectedItemIndex + 1)

          ' How to position EditorTextBox to the next ListViewItem here?
          ' The following methods return null/Nothing:
          ' ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(editorSelectedItemIndex + 1)
          ' ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lvp)
        End If
        e.Handled = True
      Case Key.Up

    End Select
  End Sub
```

So I have the position in code (PreviewKeyDown-Event) when I need to re-arrange the TextBox, but inside this routine, I can't get a result of the methods
ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index + 1) and
ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(…)

**Further tests:**
I wrote a class that inherits ListView and caches the ListViewItems when they are created in simple list of ListViewItem

```
Public Class ExtListView
  Inherits ListView

  Public Sub New()
    Dim ic = TryCast(Me.Items, System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged)
    If Not ic Is Nothing Then
      AddHandler ic.CollectionChanged, AddressOf NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler
    End If
    AddHandler Me.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged, AddressOf ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged

    _ListViewItems = New List(Of ListViewItem)
  End Sub

  Private _listViewItems As List(Of ListViewItem)
  Public ReadOnly Property ListViewItems As List(Of ListViewItem)
    Get
      Return _listViewItems
    End Get
  End Property

  Private Sub ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Me.ItemContainerGenerator.Status = Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated Then
      _listViewItems.Clear()
      For index = 0 To Me.Items.Count - 1
        _listViewItems.Add(CType(ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index), ListViewItem))
      Next
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

With this ListViewItems available, I tried to get the bounds of them:

```
Dim bounds As Rect = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(ListView.ListViewItems(editorSelectedItemIndex + 1))
```

But, however, all rectangles start at x,y-position (0, 0). I have no clue why. I expected them to be in the visual tree at a valid position.
Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: What is the ItemsSource? How is the ItemTemplate? Could you post some code (unless it is too long)?

Comment: @MarioVernari: I hope this is a manageable amount of source. I tried to post the significant lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that.

Okay, if you really want to, do that.  But there's a much, much easier way.

Add a boolean `IsEditing` and a string `EditableContent` property to your view model.  Create a data template that looks something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <Grid>
      <Border>
         <!-- normal cell content goes here -->
      </Border>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding EditableContent, Mode=TwoWay}">
         <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
               <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditing}" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
      </TextBox>
   <Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

When the `IsEditing` property is true, the `TextBox` will be displayed and the user can edit whatever's in the `EditableContent` property.  When it's false, the ordinary cell content will be displayed.

I don't know what you're sticking inside that border, but when I do this to alternate between a `TextBlock` and `TextBox` it looks identical to (say) what renaming files looks like in Windows Explorer, which I assume is what you're after.

You need to handle keypress and lost-focus events to implement the other pieces of edit-in-place functionality, but those are relatively straightforward problems once you've got the layout working.

Comment: Ok, your attempt is totally different than mine. I think your way solves many problems by design. I'm going to try today++. Thanks a lot for this valueable hint.

Comment: It took me a while to come around to this idea, but with a few significant exceptions (I'm looking at you, drag and drop), if you find yourself trying to manipulate WPF objects in code you probably need to rethink your approach.

Comment: It is working great and it drastically reduced the code in the code-behind file